# Generating Invoices and Tracking

Tags: mysql, database-design, normalization, transaction

Every 2 weeks, the system will generate the invoices for the companies.

Company will receive an invoice on the 1st and 16th every month. (It will run via Cron Job every 2 week. It scan through the order table and then add into 'invoice' table. Is there alternative?)

There are list of customers orders in the `orders` table and it also indicate which company it belong to (`orders.company_id`)

The `invoice` table calculate the total cost of the orders from `orders` table.

I am trying to figure it out how to design reasonable invoices tracking. Sometime company will have to send me the fees or sometime I send them the fees (`invoice.amount`)

**I need to track the invoices with the following:**

- when the company have sent me the amount
- when did I sent the amount to the company
- how much amount has been received from the company
- how much amount did I sent to the company
- did I receive the full amount (if not, what do I need to update on the Db?)
- invoice status (Invoice Sent, Cancelled, Amount Received, Amount Sent)

Here is the database design I have came up with:

**company table**

```
mysql> select * from company;
+----+-----------+
| id | name      |
+----+-----------+
|  1 | Company A |
|  2 | Company B |
+----+-----------+
```

Customers can select a company from my website.

**orders table**

```
mysql> select * from orders;
+----+---------+------------+------------+---------------------+-----------+
| id | user_id | company_id | total_cost | order_date          | status_id |
+----+---------+------------+------------+---------------------+-----------+
|  1 |       5 |          2 |      25.00 | 2012-02-03 23:30:24 |         1 |
|  2 |       7 |          2 |      30.00 | 2012-02-13 18:06:12 |         1 |
+----+---------+------------+------------+---------------------+-----------+
```

two customers have ordered the products from *Company B* (`orders.company_id = 2`). I know the orders fields is not enough, just simplified for you.

**orders_products table**

```
mysql> select * from orders_products;
+----+----------+------------+--------------+-------+
| id | order_id | product_id | product_name | cost  |
+----+----------+------------+--------------+-------+
|  1 |        1 |         34 | Chair        | 10.00 |
|  2 |        1 |         25 | TV           | 10.00 |
|  3 |        1 |         27 | Desk         |  2.50 |
|  4 |        1 |         36 | Laptop       |  2.50 |
|  5 |        2 |         75 | PHP Book     | 25.00 |
|  6 |        2 |         74 | MySQL Book   |  5.00 |
+----+----------+------------+--------------+-------+
```

List of products what customers have ordered.

**invoice table**

```
mysql> select * from invoice;
+----+------------+------------+---------------------+--------+-----------+
| id | company_id | invoice_no | invoice_date        | amount | status_id |
+----+------------+------------+---------------------+--------+-----------+
|  7 |          2 |        123 | 2012-02-16 23:59:59 |  55.00 |         1 |
+----+------------+------------+---------------------+--------+-----------+
```

This is where I am quite stuck on invoice tables design. I am not sure how it should be done.  Invoices will be generated every 2 weeks. From the result example `invoice.amount` is 55.00 because it has been calculated from `orders.company_id = 2` table

If the `invoice.amount` is -50.00 (minus), it mean company will need to send me the fees amount.

If the `invoice.amount` is 50.00, it mean I need to send the company the fees.

The status_id could be: (1)Invoice Sent, (2)Cancelled, (3)Completed

Do I need to add `invoice_id` field in the `orders` table? Update the `orders.invoice_id` field when row has been inserted into 'invoice' table.

**invoice_payment table**

```
mysql> select * from invoice_payment;
+----+------------+-----------------+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | invoice_id | amount_received | amount_sent | date_received       | date_sent           |
+----+------------+-----------------+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 |          1 |            0.00 |       55.00 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | 2012-02-18 22:20:53 |
+----+------------+-----------------+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

This is where I can track and update transaction.. the payment will be made via BACS.

Is this good tables design or what do I need to improve? What fields and tables I should add?

If the invoice has been generated and later I need to make the changes in `orders_products` or `orders` tables - should it recalculate the `invoice.amount` field? (I will be using PHP / MySQL).

**SQL Dump**:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `company` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

INSERT INTO `company` (`id`, `name`) VALUES
(1, 'Company A'),
(2, 'Company B');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `invoice` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `company_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `invoice_no` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `invoice_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `amount` decimal(6,2) NOT NULL,
  `status_id` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=8 ;


INSERT INTO `invoice` (`id`, `company_id`, `invoice_no`, `invoice_date`, `amount`, `status_id`) VALUES
(7, 2, 123, '2012-02-16 23:59:59', '55.00', 1);


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `invoice_payment` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `invoice_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `amount_received` decimal(6,2) NOT NULL,
  `amount_sent` decimal(6,2) NOT NULL,
  `date_received` datetime NOT NULL,
  `date_sent` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;

INSERT INTO `invoice_payment` (`id`, `invoice_id`, `amount_received`, `amount_sent`, `date_received`, `date_sent`) VALUES
(1, 1, '0.00', '55.00', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', '2012-02-18 22:20:53');


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `orders` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `company_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `total_cost` decimal(6,2) NOT NULL,
  `order_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `status_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;


INSERT INTO `orders` (`id`, `user_id`, `company_id`, `total_cost`, `order_date`, `status_id`) VALUES
(1, 5, 2, '25.00', '2012-02-03 23:30:24', 1),
(2, 7, 2, '30.00', '2012-02-13 18:06:12', 1);


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `orders_products` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `order_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `product_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `cost` decimal(6,2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=7 ;

INSERT INTO `orders_products` (`id`, `order_id`, `product_id`, `product_name`, `cost`) VALUES
(1, 1, 34, 'Chair', '10.00'),
(2, 1, 25, 'TV', '10.00'),
(3, 1, 27, 'Desk', '2.50'),
(4, 1, 36, 'Laptop', '2.50'),
(5, 2, 75, 'PHP Book', '25.00'),
(6, 2, 74, 'MySQL Book', '5.00');
```

Feel free you want to updates/add tables to Answer here.

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Cash matching**

This is a cash matching problem.  You can track this at one of two levels:

- Compare invoiced to cash figures (somewhat sloppy but this is actually how it's done for inwards business by most Lloyd's Syndicates, often called a 'written vs. signed' report).
- Maintain explicit cash allocations from cash payments broken down by invoice.

From your question I think you want to do the latter.

Typically this is done by having a separate set of cash transactions, and a bridging table that has the allocation of cash payments to invoices.  If the values are equal or the cash payment comes with a single invoice reference you can do the allocation automatically.  If there's a M:M relationship between invoices and payments you will need to do a manual matching process (doing this automatically is actually a variant of the [knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem)).

**A basic cash matching system**

Imagine that you have an invoice table, a cash payments table and an allocation table.  When you issue an invoice then you set up an invoice record in the invoices table and  a 'receivable' or 'payable' record in the allocations table.

- Invoice #1, $100
- Allocation: a record with a reference to invoice #1, 'receivable' transaction type and $100 owing.  No reference to a cash payment on this record.

Now, you get a cash payment of $100

- Cash payments (chq #12345): $100
- Allocation: a record with a reference to invoice #1 and chq #12345, 'cash' transaction type and -100 owing ($100 paid).

You can generalise this to a M:M relationship where you get multiple payments against a single invoice or a payment covering multiple invoices.  This structure also makes it quite easy to build credit control reports.  The report just needs to find invoices older than (say) 180 days that still have outstanding balances.

Here's an example of the schema plus a couple of scenarios and an aged debt query.  Unfortunately I don't have a running mysql instance to hand, so this one is for SQL Server.

```
-- ==============================================================
-- === CashMatch.sql ============================================
-- ==============================================================
--


-- === Invoices =================================================
--
create table Invoice (
       InvoiceID        int identity (1,1) not null
      ,InvoiceRef       varchar (20)
      ,Amount           money
      ,InvoiceDate      datetime
)
go

alter table Invoice
  add constraint PK_Invoice 
      primary key nonclustered (InvoiceID)
go


-- === Cash Payments ============================================
--
create table CashPayment (
       CashPaymentID    int identity (1,1) not null
      ,CashPaymentRef   varchar (20)
      ,Amount           money
      ,PaidDate         datetime
)
go

alter table CashPayment
  add constraint PK_CashPayment
      primary key nonclustered (CashPaymentID)
go




-- === Allocations ==============================================
--
create table Allocation (
       AllocationID       int identity (1,1) not null
      ,CashPaymentID      int  -- Note that some records are not
      ,InvoiceID          int  -- on one side.
      ,AllocatedAmount    money
      ,AllocationType     varchar (20)
      ,TransactionDate    datetime
)
go

alter table Allocation
  add constraint PK_Allocation
      primary key nonclustered (AllocationID)
go


-- ==============================================================
-- === Scenarios ================================================
-- ==============================================================
--
declare @Invoice1ID int
       ,@Invoice2ID int
       ,@PaymentID int


-- === Raise a new invoice ======================================
--
insert Invoice (InvoiceRef, Amount, InvoiceDate)
values ('001', 100, '2012-01-01')

set @Invoice1ID = @@identity

insert Allocation (
       InvoiceID
      ,AllocatedAmount
      ,TransactionDate
      ,AllocationType
) values (@Invoice1ID, 100, '2012-01-01', 'receivable')


-- === Receive a payment ========================================
--
insert CashPayment (CashPaymentRef, Amount, PaidDate)
values ('12345', 100, getdate())

set @PaymentID = @@identity

insert Allocation (
       InvoiceID
      ,CashPaymentID
      ,AllocatedAmount
      ,TransactionDate
      ,AllocationType
) values (@Invoice1ID, @PaymentID, -100, getdate(), 'paid')



-- === Raise two invoices =======================================
--
insert Invoice (InvoiceRef, Amount, InvoiceDate)
values ('002', 75, '2012-01-01')

set @Invoice1ID = @@identity

insert Allocation (
       InvoiceID
      ,AllocatedAmount
      ,TransactionDate
      ,AllocationType
) values (@Invoice1ID, 75, '2012-01-01', 'receivable')


insert Invoice (InvoiceRef, Amount, InvoiceDate)
values ('003', 75, '2012-01-01')

set @Invoice2ID = @@identity

insert Allocation (
       InvoiceID
      ,AllocatedAmount
      ,TransactionDate
      ,AllocationType
) values (@Invoice2ID, 75, '2012-01-01', 'receivable')


-- === Receive a payment ========================================
-- The payment covers one invoice in full and part of the other.
--
insert CashPayment (CashPaymentRef, Amount, PaidDate)
values ('23456', 120, getdate()) 

set @PaymentID = @@identity

insert Allocation (
       InvoiceID
      ,CashPaymentID
      ,AllocatedAmount
      ,TransactionDate
      ,AllocationType
) values (@Invoice1ID, @PaymentID, -75, getdate(), 'paid')

insert Allocation (
       InvoiceID
      ,CashPaymentID
      ,AllocatedAmount
      ,TransactionDate
      ,AllocationType
) values (@Invoice2ID, @PaymentID, -45, getdate(), 'paid')



-- === Aged debt report ========================================
--
select i.InvoiceRef
      ,sum (a.AllocatedAmount)                 as Owing
      ,datediff (dd, i.InvoiceDate, getdate()) as Age
  from Invoice i
  join Allocation a
    on a.InvoiceID = i.InvoiceID
 group by i.InvoiceRef
         ,datediff (dd, i.InvoiceDate, getdate())
having sum (a.AllocatedAmount) > 0
```

Comment: Mine has separate tables for invoices and payments. You could use a common table with internal linkage. Cash matching is often implemented that way in accounting systems.

Comment: I have managed to translate your SQL Server example into MySQL. I went through and I understood very well now.  What would `AllocationType` would be if I want to send client money? Do I need to insert into `CashPayment` table as well (let say paying them via BACS)?

Comment: Yes, you want a cash payment record for both incoming and outgoing payments.  The actual transaction types for the cash matching transactions are up to you.

Comment: You can match transactions from invoices in both directions against a single settlement payment if you want.  For example: Outgoing invoice for $100, incoming invoice for $50 (-50) and balancing payment incoming for $50 matched against both invoices.